# Laravel Route URL in Notification Email Defaults to HTTP

Tags: https, notifications, laravel-9

I am creating email notifications in Laravel 9 that contain a button with a URL. I am using the name attribute from the route to pass along the proper route from the web.php file.

When the user gets the email notification, the URL defaults to "http://" rather than "https://".

I have the proper HTTPS redirect on the server, but I'd like the original URL to default to HTTPS. Any idea how to do this?

---

Example route from web.php:

```
Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
```

Example notification button line in the HomeController:

```
$notify_data = [
    ... content stuff here ...
    'url'     => route('home' ),
];

$user->notify( new Step3($notify_data) );
```

And finally the button in the Step3 Notification:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ... content stuff here ...
        ->action('View Dashboard', $this->notify_data['url']);
}
```

Expectation:
URL in email: https://www.example-domain.com/home

Current result:
URL in email: http://www.example-domain.com/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [secure_url](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-secure-url) method

```
'url'     => secure_url(route( 'home', [], false)),
```

The secure_url function generates a fully qualified HTTPS URL to the given path. Additional URL segments may be passed in the function's second argument: